# Dynamically creating Nanoc rules and compile directives

Tags: ruby, nanoc

I would like to generate Rules DSL from the helper module. I have custom blog helper and i would like it to generate RSS feeds automatically so I don't have to specify any compile and routing rules in the `Rules` file as long as specific metadata is present.

So lets say I have my blog in `news.erb` and `news\*.md` directory. Erb file has blog configuration in its metadata section (number of articles to show, ordering etc..) In preprocessing I have `create_blog` function which generates `\page\N` depending on the metadata I have in `news.erb`. If this metadata includes `rss: true` section I would like the `create_blog` function to also register 2 aditional rules (if those are not previously defined) and 1 aditional file `/feeds/news.xml`:

```
compile /feeds\/.+/  do
  filter :erb
end

route /feeds\/.+/ do
    item.identifier.chop + '.xml'
end
```

I can generate the file all right, but in order to keep the site modularized I want to create those above rules in the `create_blog` itself. This allows me to later, if I want to remove the blog, just comment out the module and not change `Rules` file.